# How can I remotely view network configurations on Windows-2008-R2 via command line?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have several Windows-2008-R2 servers on my LAN.  Each server has 4+ NICs, including some teamed NICs.  I need to monitor the name and status of each configuration, preferably via the command line, to-be scripted.  Is there a way to do this remotely via another windows machine on the LAN?

The current method is to RDP into each machine, open "View Network Connections", and track each visually.

Comment: ipconfig/all? I'm not clear on what you mean when you say that you need to monitor the name and status.

Comment: also thought of ipconfig with psexec, but this really calls for a proper solution

Comment: Clarification: when I say "name" and "status", these are the columns you see when you open "View Network Connections" and view details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard way to query NIC teaming configuration because this is done with proprietary driver-based mechanisms. Broadcom drivers, for example, do it differently than Intel drivers. You'd probably end up needing to parse the proprietary configuration information these drivers store in the registry in order to figure out what the teaming configuration was.

You could use `ipconfig /all` as @joeqwerty suggested to get the IP configuration information. You could also use `netsh dump`, which will give you the interface names and IP configuration. You won't get teaming configuration out of either of those, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GWMI commandlet in powershell.  You can use a -computername parameter to specify the remote machines.  I believe the two namespaces you'll want to play with are Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to use a monitoring solution like Nagios? Take a look at http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html.

Besides, if this is a brandname server, monitoring can be done using the vendor-provided applications, like Dell OMSA with IT-Assistant for example.

Answer (score 0):

this links may help you. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726987.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8781